# How to place an optional break with second line flushed to right?

Tags: line-breaking, plain-tex, penalty

I wrote a table of the `\advance` operator.
If the line is too long, I want a break, and the second line flushed to right.
I tried to get inspiration from the macro `\signed` presented in the TeXbook, page 106.

```
\parindent=0pt
\obeylines
\def\signed #1{{\penalty50\hskip0pt plus-1fill\hbox{}\hfill\ #1}}
{\tt -1pt} advanced by {\tt 1pt} =\signed {\tt 0.0pt.}
{\tt 0pt plus -1pt minus -1pt} advanced by {\tt 1pt plus -1pt minus -1pt} =\signed {\tt 1.0pt plus -2.0pt minus -2.0pt.}
```

The first statement is short, it is on one line with a space. Good.

The second statement is a bit long. It breaks after the '='.
But here, the second line stays at left. Why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert some `\nobreak` macros.

```
\parindent=0pt

\def\signed #1{{%
  \unskip % in case there is space preceding \signed
  \nobreak\hskip 0pt plus -1fill % no break here
  \penalty50 % possible break here
  \hbox{}% something not discardable
  \nobreak\hfill % no break at this skip
  \ % a normal space
  #1% the text to typeset
}}

X\dotfill X

{\tt -1pt} advanced by {\tt 1pt} =\signed {\tt 0.0pt.}

{\tt 0pt plus -1pt minus -1pt} advanced by {\tt 1pt plus -1pt minus -1pt}
= \signed {\tt 1.0pt plus -2.0pt minus -2.0pt.}

\bye
```

If no break is taken at at the penalty, the two infinite skips will cancel each other. Otherwise the first infinite skip will do nothing.

[image]

Comment: The normal space is glue, and it is preceded by another glue (which is discardable). Therefore no break will happen between the two glues.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Yes, that’s true

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in the TeXbook, your `\signed` macro lacks the `\nobreak` before the `\hfill`. In order to avoid the `\penalty50`, the line will be broken before the `\hfill` (making the `\hfill` disappear).

Answer (score 1):

@egreg's answer works fine. (thank you!)

However, I was not totally satisfied with it because I don't understand why the first infinite skip does nothing when there is a break.

I finally came to a working solution that I understand better.

```
\def\signed #1{{%
\nobreak\hfil% infinite glue at end of first line if break
\penalty50%
\hfilneg\hskip0pt plus-1fill% compensates for infinite glues if no break, else discarded
\hbox{}%
\nobreak\hfill% infinite glue at beginning of second line,
% with 2 'l's because of the hfil at end of paragraph
\ #1%
}}
```